# Is there a way to change the URL to show all answers to a question, not just the first X answers?

Tags: support

If I go to this URL, I see around 30 answers to the question:

[jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks)

If I go to this URL (by clicking the "2" at the bottom of the page), I see the rest of the answers:

[jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

Is there a way to show **all** the answers on a single page?  I tried `page=all` but it didn't work.

The reason I ask is because there are some questions I'd like to sync to my Kindle for handy reference.  (I could also get to the page through Wi-Fi, but I don't always have Wi-Fi available, e.g. at work.)

Comment: Rats, I cannot even [suggest a Greasemonkey script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19495/148310) since it's a Kindle.

Comment: Well, I'm converting the page to Kindle format using the Kindle It plugin for Chrome on a Windows 7 PC.  But it would still be nice if showing all answers Just Worked without having to use a custom script or something.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to epxand the page to show all answers in the ordinary view.

All answers (including vote & revision history) are also available at the timeline.
For your question, this are the URLs:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks) - The question
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/182630/timeline/ - Timeline
- The timeline method contains much noise. You can also use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/question-answers) to show all answers for a given question. The response format is JSON or JSONP, a script to parse these formats can be created easily.

If you don't like clicking on the buttons, you can also use this Stack App:

- [Infinite Scrolling - [Never Click Another Page Number Again!]](https://stackapps.com/questions/2614/infinite-scrolling-never-click-another-page-number-again)